# Packages not installing on django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to install any packages and I am unable to. I use `pip install package`. But, after successfully installing. When I try to run the application, I get a the following error.

```
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

This seems to be a common problem discuss in a lot of groups, but I have not found any solutions. I've been working on this all day. Please help. New to django.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/0tAtr4NBJ_4
http://www.techlighting.info/django-channels-tutorial-1-creating-a-chat-application/

I think that my project is not connecting to the packages correctly.

Here is my file relationship.

This is where the project is:

> Documents > Projects > hosproject > catalog, manage.py, hosproject2, venv

This is where the packages are

> Documents > trydjango > lib >python3.7>site.packages>packages

Here is my istalled app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'catalog',
    'import-export', #this breaks when I try to install today
    'django_tables2', # this I installed hsitorically ( a month ago and works)
    #'csvimport.app.CSVImportConf', # this breaks it
]
```

Basically any package will break it if I try an install now. Packages that I installed historically work.

Comment: Can you show `installed_apps` of your setting file here?

Comment: Do you have _init_.py file in settings module of your project?

Comment: @Majhi Yes, I have an init file in my project. I've actually tried to rebuild the project from scratch three times, following best conventions and it does not fix this problem.

Comment: @PS1212 Added installed packages.

Comment: @JR: Are in the right venv? can you confirm if the missing package is present in your current venv? Could you share results of `pip list` in your virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the third party packages in your settings file like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # third party packages
    'package',
]
```

Comment: Yes, there are there. This is not the problem.